# Jquery AJAX calls to NLB (Network load balancer) and cross domain scripting issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, rest

We have a simple dashboard application that makes Jquery AJAX calls to RESTFUL WCF service (whose endpoints are exposed using webHttpBinding). Things work as expected as long as UI application and service are hosted on a single box. I understand the cross site scripting and cross domain scripting issue and the reason we can not use JSONP is we have wcf service under NTLM security.

Now in production environment, we have two servers hosting both application and service behind NLB. My question is, will the Jquery AJAX calls made from browser to NLB server be treated as cross domain? If yes, how can I make these two servers trusted?

Answer (score 0):

For cross domain jQuery ajax calls we have only 2 reliable options:

1: use a proxy script that makes the request for you on the same domain

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1430/aspnet-proxy-page--used-for-cross-domain-requests-from-ajax-and-javascript/

2: make the cross-domain server support CORS.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Also there is another option(JSON-P) that is not recommended due to security concerns:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/